# How to update a column of a table depending on the other column automatically in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my table, in one hour, 50 students will submit their marks in some exam everyday.

Following is the table

```
ID    StudID  Marks  Rank
1     101     56 
2     102     23
3     103     84
4     104     96
5     105     44
```

I want when all these records are inserted, the rank should get auto calculated and get insterted against each record.
For example, Rank column will get filled like this:

```
ID    StudID  Marks  Rank
1     101     56     3
2     102     23     5
3     103     84     2
4     104     96     1
5     105     44     4
```

I want to create a single query for this in mysql. Would it be done in a single query or will it require any functions or procedure? How should I write query, function or procedure for above logic in mysql?

Note: I have to implement above logic using PHP.

Comment: Do you want the rank as a column in the table or as a derived value whenever you query the results?

Comment: @AgRizzo - I want rank as column because every student has a profile in my site. I am giving them the feature that they can see their rank of any day when they go to their profile and select date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT  StudID, Marks,
                 (SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT b.Marks) 
                  FROM  tableName b
                  WHERE a.Marks <= b.Marks
                  ) as rank
          FROM    tableName a
          ORDER   BY Marks DESC
          ) b ON a.StudID = b.StudID
SET a.Rank = b.rank
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e17e/1)

Comment: thanks for your help. just one question...is this solution optimized for 5000 records?

Comment: 5k-record is not too much. Do you have indexes set on the table?

Comment: Try adding one, `ALTER TABLE TableName ADD INDEX(Marks, StudID)` and execute the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming the student rerun the insert query, so when the student submit their mark they run query insert into ...
Try this:

```
INSERT INTO <thetable> (ID, StudID, Marks, Rank)
VALUES (<theid>, <thestudentid>, <themark>, NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Rank = (SELECT COUNT(*)+1
                                  FROM <thetable>
                                 WHERE Rank IS NOT NULL);
```

Another assumption: **initial value for column "Rank" is NULL**, or if **empty string** change the condition `Rank IS NOT NULL` to `Rank = ''`